# gapi.client.load error "Ignoring mismatched auth param scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-plus-one, google-api-client

From today I'm starting having troubles getting user's friends list with JS, when i load the plus api with "`gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', callbackFn)`" I see in firebug logs the message

**"Ignoring mismatched auth param scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"**

And then when I call `gapi.client.plus.people.list({'userId': 'me', 'collection': 'visible', 'fields': 'items(id)')`

It fails saying **"`Invalid string value: 'visible'. Allowed values: [pages]`"**... when it's not true!
Yesterday was working fine, I could get my friend's ids and today stopped...
Even trying to create a new application and api key always get the same error, something changed on big G plus apis?

I'm having headache, anyone having this trouble?

---

Update 1:
I've found an example from google developers guide and followed line by line:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js
That's exactly whath i'm doing and... same result! :(

Comment: Making progress... i discovered that Ignoring mismatched auth param scope was due to initializing interactivepost before authenticating the user... but still no luck, the errror "Invalid string value: 'visible'. Allowed values: [pages]" is still there... any help would be appriciated ;)

Comment: Solved, it was a bug introduced yesterday in javascript client libs and fixed in late night, now it's working! Thanks